# XCode does not create pod dependencies for React Native Project

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

Project config:

```
Xcode @ 13.4.1 (13F100) 
cocoapods @ 1.11.3
React Native @ 0.64.0
iOS target @ 11.0
```

I can't build this mobile project and XCode says there's file missing.

```
fatal error: module map file '/Users/myself/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NextLevelSessionExporter/NextLevelSessionExporter.modulemap' not found
```

When I run `pod install`, says its has run without errors, but checking  into `Xcode/DerivedData/myproject/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator` and it does not show all the dependencies folder as it should.

I tried

- Removing `~/.cocoapods` folder
- Deleting `ios/Pods/` folder and `Podfile.lock`
- Deleting `DerivedData` folder completely

No progress so far.

Any guidance will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

1. Delete `cocoapods` folder, `ios/Pods/` folder and `Podfile.lock` file
2. Deleting `DerivedData` folder
3. delete `node_modules` folder
4. Run command `pod install` or `pod repo update`

Hope it will help you!